# How to remove global background color from a activity android

Tags: android, background, background-color

I have set the background color for the whole project by adding in the theme.

```
<item name="android:background">@color/primary_background</item>
<item name="background">@color/primary_background</item>
```

Now  the problem is whenever I try to use bottomnavigation bar or any other designing library like I am using  [for the tour](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3730). In case of bottomnavigationview if I set the global background then I will not able to change the bottom bar background color. In the tour case the background set to global background color.

Is there any way I can unset the global background color for the activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I created the other general theme: without_background_color_theme and move all your attributes to this theme except background color. Then your background color theme will extend without_background_color_theme. Now you can set the Activity's theme which you want to unset background color to without_background_color_theme.

```
<style name="background_color_theme" parent="without_background_color_theme>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
<item name="android:colorBackground">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
</style>
```

Comment: thanks. simple trick. how I have miss this. thanks a lot. @Luong